# Unknown Error with thread blocked on Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, vert.x

I'm using the version 3.8.1 of Vertx with Java 11.05 and I configured the verticles to use Hazelcast.

Everything works fine and the application runs without any issues. However, I begin to receive the error a thread has been blocked on Hazelcast.
[image]

I'm checking the error logs for the verticles and there are not blocked threads in the code or any other issues. 
The issue only happens when the application is under load test. Also, the issue not seems to affect the services.

The services are responding without any problems.

Does anyone have the same issue before?

Comment: Can you post your question on the [Vert.x user group](https://vertx.io/community)? StackOverflow isn't the right place to have a discussion

Comment: I already posted it there, I hope anyone can give me some information about it.

Comment: Can you post the link to your question here?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/vertx/vCfuslt57Co/3XrXsiD6AwAJ

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to tsegismont.

I find a solution to this issue. The original conversation is on google forums. But the answer is to upgrade the version of Hazelcast.

The version that solves the issue is 3.11.

I used this POM call for fix the Hazelcast library.

```
<!-- specify Hazelcast version default 3.10.5 -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you keep having issues, the problem could be in Hazelcast as something referred to brain split syndrome on the cluster.

https://community.pega.com/knowledgebase/articles/system-administration/split-brain-syndrome-and-cluster-fracturing-faqs

Also, Hazelcast has some specific configuration for the cluster that can help to solve the issue.

Kind regards,
Juan